# Windows Socket Encapsulation - Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock2, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm learning winsockets and got a linker error when calling the `socket(af, type, protocol)` function in a constructor.

main.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    nmd::Server *server = new nmd::Server();

    //TODO: Logic

    delete server;
    server = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Server.h

```
#pragma once

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

namespace nmd {
class Server {
public:
    Server();
    virtual ~Server();
private:
    SOCKET socket_;
};
}
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"

nmd::Server::Server() {
    socket_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == socket_)
        throw 1; // TODO: proper exception handling
}

nmd::Server::~Server() {}
```

When I try to build it, an unresolved external symbol error occur. In detail:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12 referenced in function "public: __thiscall nmd::Server::Server(void)" (??0Server@nmd@@QAE@XZ)
```

What am I missing here? I want to know the source of this problem, not only the solution. What makes the compiler to belive that `nmd::Server::Server()` is undefined when I put the `socket(...)` function in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [`Ws2_32.lib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx) to your linker command to resolve that function.

Comment: Maaaan, I just did this in an other project and just realized. Solved, thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Please check if it works when You place socket initialization on initializer list:

```
nmd::Server::Server(): socket_(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
{
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == socket_)
        throw 1; // TODO: proper exception handling
}
```

Comment: This is syntactically incorrent, my friend :( SOCKET has no c-tor like this, or maybe I don't get what you are up to?!